# Can I use Celery eventlet pools with Django+Postgres?

Tags: django, celery, psycopg2, django-celery, eventlet

Does celery do any magic to make Django queries non-blocking when using an eventlet pool?

If not, is there a known good way to make it so?

Answer (score 0):

Eventlet provides `monkey_patch()` to make as much stuff as possible non-blocking. Including sockets (covers any pure Python database library) and special cases for mysqldb and psycopg and Celery worker type `eventlet` calls that patcher as far as I know. If your queries are still blocking, try `monkey_patch(psycopg=True)`.